# React state - what I am doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn reactjs and building small app that takes in names and then shows the names..

I have an input form, and I am able to get data from input form after clicking submit into my state object called `names`.

however I am stuck on passing the state from the parent to another component that is inside of my `ShowNames` component:

So, in App, I am doing this render:

```
render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <InputName addToState={this.addToState}/>
                <ShowName renderName={this.renderName}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Then ShowName component has following:

```
var ShowName = React.createClass({

    render : function() {
        return (
            <ListOfNames renderName={this.props.renderName}/>
        )
    }
});
```

So I made

```
var ListOfNames = React.createClass({

    render : function() {
        return (
            <ul renderName={this.props.renderName}>
                {Object.keys(this.state.names).map(this.renderName)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

But the issue is it says Cannot read property 'names' of null.  Can someone help?

Comment: `state` is not defined for your `ListOfNames` component

Comment: how to pass the state which is stored in {names} down?  I have to create one more something like passState={this.state.names} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise the state otherwise the state will be null.

```
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { names: [] };
    },

    // all the rest here
}
```

---

**EDIT**

after seeing the code I noticed a couple of errors, the updated code is now here: http://jsbin.com/sewoxu/edit?js,output

So what the main error was that the render function of `ShowName` was using the state to get the names, but the names where passed via property:

```
<ShowName renderName={this.renderName} names={this.state.names}/>
```

so in this case to access the names attribute you need to do:

```
this.props.names
```

Also in the example I have moved the `renderName` function inside the `ShowName` component.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hello sir I have this already in the App copmonent : `getInitialState : function() {
  return {
   names : {}
  }
 },`

Comment: @user3152131 can you provide an example on jsbin or jsfiddle? :)

Comment: please i am sorry the site is not loading for me can you able to see on pastebin?  http://pastebin.com/8AMY39y3

Comment: @user3152131 I've updated my answer, hope everything is clear now :)

Comment: thank you Patrick sir you have really helped me to understand.  react is really confuseing and very difficult compared to the prior learnings

Comment: hello Patrick sir one more question - it is OK not to need the `state={this.props.names}` in the <ul></ul> correct?

Comment: @user3152131 if pass something as a property so like `<ul state={x}></ul>` the ul component will receive this parameter inside the props attribute, so you'd need to use `this.props.state` which is not really the best thing.